# Add +7 to variable $i each time button is pressed, no page reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, button

**My Problem: I don't know how to add +7 to variable $i each time a button is pressed. I tried with isset($_POST) but than you can only execute the code block to add +7 to $i once i want it to be unlimited.**

The function below uses variable $i to determine how many days you want to go forward, so in my case when $i = 7 it jumps 7 days forward. This function works fine.

***Timeschedule.php***

```
// UPDATED: Used other function instead to show what desired results i want to achieve

public function getDate($i){
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
        $datetime = new DateTime('today');
        $datetime->modify('+' . $i . 'day');
        $output = $datetime->format('d-m-Y');

        return $output;
}
```

**Orderstep_1.php**

```
// This file includes timeschedule.php
include timeschedule.php

<input name="testbutton" class="testbutton" id="testbutton" type="submit" value="=>" />
```

Now i used isset with post but that can only execute the code once on the page and i need i to be unlimited.

```
if(isset($_POST['testbutton'])){
   $i = $i + 7;
}
```

Hope you guys can send me in the right direction.

***UPDATED:***

This code outputs the data

```
$testObject = new TimeSchedule();
$date1 = $testObject->getDate(0); echo $date1;
```

Output result

```
02-02-2015
```

Output i want to achieve after button clicks

```
09-02-2015
16-02-2015 
23-02-2015
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to implement client side logic with PHP. PHP is run once, on the server side, and the output (page) is sent to the client. After that, the variables in php do not exist anymore.

For client side logic, you'll probably need javascript instead. Javascript is run on client side, unlike PHP.

You'll need to rewrite `getDay` in javascript, use a context or some global variable for `i`, and pass that `i` to `getDay` each time the button is clicked.

Another option would be storing `i` in javascript but keeping `getDay` as PHP code, then whenever `i` changes, send an ajax request to a url that you're going to create that calls `getDay`, like getDay.php?i=0. getDay returns the date, and you update your date in javascript.

Your logic is simple and it'd probably better to keep it in client side, but for complex algorithms, you might want to run your methods in server side instead, since client side codes are visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot you made clear how i'm supposed to continue now, however i'm not that familiar yet with ajax requests. Can you give me an example how i can keep my php code but store the $i in javascript? I know how to use javascript but would love to learn some new stuff :)

Comment: Well, the most primitive way would be to store it globally (under `window`). I wouldn't recommend storing the variable directly. Instead, I'd have a class (or a dictionary) that stores all my client side variables/logic under window. For example, window.myApp (or myApp for short, since global variables are defined to be under `window`) would store all your variables including your `i` (let's name it `elapsedDay`). You start with initializing `elapsedDay` to zero. Then whenever the button is pressed, you update `elapsedDay` and send an ajax request.

Comment: You can send ajax requests directly in javascript but using a known framework like jQuery would ease the process a lot. Take a look at this:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: And on a completely unrelated topic, you can use frameworks that help implement MVC logic in client side. In those, you'd be storing your `elapsedDay` in your controller. Have a look at angular.js for example, which is, though very heavy, a nice example of MVC. As I said before, this is totally unrelated but might ease your development a lot :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the additional information, i'm definitely going to have a look at angular.js and ajax and the solution you offered me :)